# str object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am using unittest example in selenium python

tried google did not get correct solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
#import HtmlTestRunner




class googlesearch(unittest.TestCase):
    driver = 'driver'


    @classmethod
    def setupClass(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.maximize_window()


    def test_search_automationstepbystep(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation Step By step")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").click()


    def test_search_naresh(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Naresh")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").click()


    @classmethod
    def teardownClass(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
        print("Test completed")

if __name__== "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: `driver = 'driver'` so `driver` is a `str`. What did you expect with you called `get` on a string?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned @Error - Syntactical Remorse , driver is a string due to your first line of code in your class.

If you are planning to access the driver globally  make sure to declare the `driver` as global.